# Consecutive ones in a PRG

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I'm trying to solve this problem.
[image]

I tried this. Consider distinguisher $D$ such that

$D(c) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{If there is at least $2\log_2n$ consecutive 1's} \\
0 & \text{o.w.} \end{cases}$.

Since $G$ is PRG

$$|\mathbb{P}[D(G(U_n)) = 1] - \mathbb{P}[D(U_{\ell(n)}) = 1]| \leq \varepsilon(n)$$

where $\varepsilon(n)$ is a negligible function and $U_t$ is a uniformly distributed $t$-bit string. I think $\mathbb{P}[D(G(U_n)) = 1]$ is what the problem wants, but I can't continue with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high-level way to approach this question is to define the quantities

$$p(n) = \Pr[D(G(U)) = 1], \qquad p^*(n) = \Pr[D(U') = 1]$$

that you have done, and note that they must be within a negligible factor, e.g.

$$|p(n) - p^*(n)| \leq \epsilon(n)$$

You should plausibly be able to compute $p^*(n)$ (it is a purely statistical calculcation), which implies things about $p(n)$, which is what you care about.

In slightly more detail, a straightforward argument (that I will omit as this appears to be homework) shows that

1. $p^*(n) \leq \frac{1}{\ell(n)}$,
2. $p^*(n) \geq \frac{1}{\ell(n)^2}$ (one can obtain the tighter bound $p^*(n) \geq \Omega(\frac{1}{\ell(n)\log\ell(n)})$, but you don't need this for your purposes),

which can be paired with the above discussion to answer your question.
So you can reduce to (trying to) prove the aformentioned bounds on $p^*(n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip. At the first I was attempting to come up with a recursive formula for the number of strings that have at least $2\lg{\ell(n)}$ consecutive ones, which was hard.  However, this bounds where easily obtained. Thanks.